# Знак препинания в "А почему стоит обратить внимание на этот продукт - объяснит Вася Ложкин."

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение, косвенная

> А почему стоит обратить внимание на этот продукт - объяснит Вася Ложкин.

Добрый день! Правильно ли тут расставлены знаки препинания?

Заранее спасибо. Всем читающим большого добра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [такое правило в справочнике Розенталя (пункт 1)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142), которое гласит, что когда придаточная часть идёт перед главной и когда пауза длиннее, чем обычно между главной и придаточной, то ставится тире. И если  придаточная с вопросительной интонацией, то это правило тем более подходит, и там даже есть несколько примеров с вопросительными придаточными:

> Как быть в таких случаях — спрашивают радиослушатели.
> Ответила ли она на его письмо или нет — он так и не узнал.
> Он придёт, но когда — не знаю.